# how to plot rotated densities on a line plot

Tags: r, plot

i would like to create a line plot with densities rotated for different values on x-axis in R

suppose, i have three densities h1, h2, h3

```
h1<-rnorm(100); h2<-rnorm(100,2,1); h3<-rnorm(100,5,1);
```

I want to plot a line (say means of h1, h2 and h3 on x-axis) and the density plots of h1,h2 and h3 should be rotated (axis should not be visible) on the line plot at respective locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? I found your question to be somewhat unclear.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)

#reshape into long format; also calculate mean for each group
tmp <- data.frame(h1=rnorm(100), h2=rnorm(100,2,1), h3=rnorm(100,5,1))

ggplot(ddply(melt(tmp),.variables=.(variable),transform,mean=mean(value)),aes(x=mean,y=value,group=variable)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes i need something like this. I need a plot with x-axis: h1, h2 and h3; y-axis: 0 to 100 (say); a line joining the means of h1, h2 and h3; densities of h1, h2 and h3 rotated by 90 degree at h1, h2 and h3.

Comment: @Chandra Try adding `+ stat_summary(aes(group=NULL),fun.y="mean",geom="line")
` to get the line.

Comment: Thanks, i got it, but can't i get density? i tried using geom_density instead of _violin, doesn't work.

Comment: `geom_violin` draws the densities and does the rotation. You cannot replace it with something else. If you truly want to have normal densities, then you need to find another (probably more laborious) way.

Comment: yes geom_violin gives the rotated density, but it gives mirrored density also. is there any way to avoid this? and i don't need normal densities, i have data sets and need to plot the densities. Thanks for your help.